# Sanitize or treatment of string in editor via shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I have a string of data that's getting passed to the page via shortcode, but the original developer of the shortcode did not account for how I'm necessarily planning on using the data on the page, unfortunately. I'm creating a "leaving this website" type of page, and the user will be presented with a message, and then automatically redirected to the offsite page.

In short, the custom field holds a URL for the offsite page, which I'm then passing as a `$_REQUEST` variable to another "you're about to leave" page. Because there are multiple `&` and `?`, the URL breaks...as do my vars. Not always...just when there's multiple `&` and `?`.

I am hoping there's some way to urlencode easy solution from a shortcode, where I can just wrap the shortcode around my text and have it encoded. I'm aware there are PHP shortcode plugins out there, but from a security standpoint, I'm hoping to stay away from that one.

Perhaps maybe I'm thinking about this wrong, though?

Example of what I have:

```
<a href="/leaving?company=[name]&url=[website]">Visit Website</a>
```

What I'm hoping to end up with:

```
<a href="/leaving?company=[urlencode][name][/urlencode]&url=[urlencode][website][/urlencode]">
Visit Website
</a>
```

Should I just be creating a custom shortcode in my Theme's `functions.php` for something like this? The functionality seems fairly straightforward. Just getting hung up.

**UPDATE**

Attempting to use Caleb's solution, but ran into issues. Now I'm doing `do_shortcode()` on the content, but still running into the same encoding issue mentioned in the comments below.

```
<?php
function shortcode_urlencode( $atts, $content = '' ) {
    return esc_url(do_shortcode($content));
}
add_shortcode( 'urlencode', 'shortcode_urlencode' );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe [esc_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url) is what you're looking for?

here's shortcode code:

```
add_shortcode('urlencode','shortcode_urlencode');
function shortcode_urlencode($atts,$content = '') {
    return esc_url(do_shortcode($content));
}
```

not tested, but should work.

Comment: I think this is exactly what was needed, however I'm running into an issue. The values in the $_REQUEST string are shortcodes where it's being output, and those shortcodes are from another plugin. When surrounded by `[urlencode]` and `[/urlencode]`, the other plugin's shortcodes are losing their shortcodiness...and it's the name of the shortcode itself being "encoded", rather than the data the shortcode `[name]` is intending to output.

Comment: e.g., if `[name]` is equal to `ABC Widgets & Co.`, we're seeing something like this `[urlencode][name][/urlencode]`  output as `name` instead of `ABC+Widgets+%26+Co.`...which is my hopeful output.

Comment: updated answer; try that.

Comment: Thanks. Unless I'm missing something, though, that's the same as I put in my update at the top of the post. For some reason, that still doesn't work. It's still outputting `name` when I do `[urlencode][name][/urlencode]` rather than `ABC+Widgets+%26+Co.`. What are we missing?!   :|

Comment: can you update your question with the code that handles the `name` shortcode?

Comment: It was actually a simplified example I was giving for purposes of here, but I'm using the [store locator plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/store-locator-le/) plugin. They have a shortcode `[slp_location name]` to output the store's company name, and another shortcode `[slp_location url wrap website]` to output the store's website URL. I need to encode both of these, but trying to do so without hacking the plugin...since updates would overwrite my changes.

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do: `<a href="/leaving?company=[urlencode][slp_location name][/urlencode]&url=[urlencode][slp_location url wrap website][/urlencode]">[slp_location name]</a>`

Comment: can you confirm the shortcode name is correct? I haven't looked through the entire it in, but I did find some shortcodes, and slp_location is not there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17237/discussion-between-will-ashworth-and-caleb).